# EF: Deleting from Many-to-Many (Bridge) table

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-4

I've got a setup similar to this:

```
Table1 
    id1 (int)
    name (varchar)

Table 2
    id2 (int)
    name (varchar)

Bridge
    id1 (fk to Table1)
    id2 (fk to Table2)
```

As you all know, in the EF, an object won't exist to represent Bridge. Instead, Table1 will contain a collection of Table2's and Table2 will contain a collection of Table1's.

Let's say I have a single Table1 record associated with 5 Table2's.

How do I delete all Table2 references **efficiently**? I only want them deleted from the Bridge table...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just clear the references and then save the changes - I don't think it deletes the Table2 records, but I may be wrong:

```
var query = from item in context.Table1
            where item.id1 == id1
            select item;

var table1 = query.Single();
table1.Table2s.Clear();

context.SaveChanges();
```